# How can I pass column names in an R function?

Tags: r

I want to create a dataframe inside the function that is a selection of columns in the dataframe d

```
QPP<-function(dat,xvar,yvar){
  varx <<- dat[,c(xvar)]
  vary <<- dat[,c(yvar)]
  a <- cbind(varx,vary) 
  a <- as.data.frame(a)
  #Perform some operations
}

QPP(dat=d,xvar = area,yvar = f.ecdf)
```

But I get an error message:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : argument is missing, with no default

1. How can I fix this?
2. Alternatively, can I do the selection of column names in one step instead of selecting and then cbinding it? I am not sure how to pass the column names.

   ```
   dput(droplevels(head(d,10)))
   structure(list(area = c(96.8656, 96.8656, 562.0274, 117.5855, 
   117.5855, 117.5855, 117.5855, 117.5855, 117.5855, 117.5855), 
   tp = c(1.5, 1, 0.5, 4.5, 6, 8.25, 4.25, 5.75, 10.75, 20.25
   ), f.ecdf = c(0.887918176006819, 0.812380140634988, 0.760387811634349, 
   0.0372895802258683, 0.00809716599190283, 0.0310036224163648, 
   0.300660558278287, 0.441721713189857, 0.152354570637119, 
   0.386852759428937)), .Names = c("area", "tp", "f.ecdf"), row.names = c(NA, 
   -10L), class = c("data.table", 
   "data.frame"))
   ```

Comment: Try with `QPP(dat=d,xvar = "area",yvar = "f.ecdf")`

Comment: I have tried that. I don't get a dataframe with the numbers, but a dataframe with the names area and f.ecdf in it. Do I have to attach the dataset first ?

Comment: Why don't you just do `dat[,c("area","f.ecdf")]`? Why the need for this function?

Comment: add `return(a)` at the end of function or change `a <- as.data.frame(a)` to `as.data.frame(a)`

Comment: @aichao I need to operate on that dataframe. Please see edit.

Comment: don't `attach` data.frames, use standard evaluation instead

Comment: If you mean that you need to operate on the selected data frame inside the function `QPP`, then I would select first using `dat[,c("area","f.ecdf")]` and then pass that to `QPP`.

Comment: @aichao But that would defeat the purpose of writing the function since the goal is to do this operation again and again with a single call.

Comment: Okay this is what I discovered. I was importing my dataset d using fread which gives me a data table. Once I turned that into a dataframe instead, this problem subsides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is perfectly fine. There is issue with the way you are passing the argument. You are supposed to pass strings as variable names.

Try this `QPP(dat=d,xvar = "area" ,yvar = "f.ecdf")`

Now, this happens because if you notice `df[,c("col_name")]` the argument "col_name" is string

Regarding your question 2: This is how you can do it one step without using `cbind`

```
QPP<-function(dat,xvar,yvar)
{
colnames<- c(xvar, yvar)
new_df <<- dat[, c(colnames)]
}

QPP(dat=d,xvar = "area" ,yvar = "f.ecdf")
```

Comment: I have tried passing string. I am getting this. I mentioned the problem in the comments as well. Not sure what the issue is... 

new_df
[1] "area"   "f.ecdf"

Comment: Okay, I started a fresh R session and it works now. Thanks. Not sure why it wasn't working before....

Comment: Okay this is what I discovered. I was importing my dataset d using fread which gives me a data table. Once I turned that into a dataframe instead, this problem subsides.